# Redshift performs an ANALYZE even with STATUPDATE OFF

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I am loading some records into Redshift in a batched manner, but it performs the analyze step before every load, even though I have STATUPDATE turned off.
These are the exact commands I run:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE staging (LIKE tablename);
COPY staging FROM '<s3 path>' 
CREDENTIALS '<credentials>' 
COMPUPDATE OFF 
STATUPDATE OFF 
JSON 'auto';
INSERT INTO versioned.factset_fundamentals_basic SELECT * FROM staging
```

On the redshift console, I see `COPY ANALYZE staging` as soon as the `COPY` command executes. Is there a way to turn this analyze step off?

Comment: Are you sure that the `ANALYZE` is due to the `COPY` statement? `CREATE TEMP TABLE` also runs an `ANALYZE` [automatically](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html#r_ANALYZE-usage-notes) on the created table too.

Comment: I tried recreating your case but I did not see the ANALYZE process.

Comment: You're right, I do think the ANALYZE comes from the temp table. Is there any way to stop this?